# How can I disable chrome extensions (when Chrome is unresponsive)?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

I'm having a problem where Chrome won't ever fully start (cursor just spins indefinitely and can't use the any menus or buttons in Chrome). I think it is due to an extension I installed but since the browser is unresponsive, I can't do anything through Chrome itself.

Is there a flag to disable all extensions for Chrome or a config file I can manually edit to disable extensions so I can figure out what exactly is causing it? I'd prefer to not have to blow it away and reinstall as I might just install the offending extension again (assuming that is what is causing the issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but starting up in incognito mode prohibits Chrome from using extensions automatically (I think).  You might be able to start with the `--incognito` flag and uninstall the offending extension.  Let me know if that works!

Comment: Ah, should have thought of incognito mode. Thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can press **Shift+Esc** to get **Task Manager** in chrome, and then kill the required extension.