# Turn off all extensions without running chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

When I start chrome it runs 2 processes for 25% cpu usage each, with single empty page. I can't use anything, menus don't open.

[image: Task manager]

But when starting with --disable-extensions it works ok. So the problem must be with one of extensions. The problem is that I can't disable extensions in this mode becouse list is empty.

What i tried:

- remove all files from C:\Users\Tomashu\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions
- reset chrome settings (chrome://settings/resetProfileSettings)
- edit Preferences (https://superuser.com/a/255018/1808236) - there is no "state" in this file

Is there any way to turn off all extensions so they can be later turned one by one?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open Google Chrome with extensions disabled / turned off?](https://superuser.com/questions/254579/how-to-open-google-chrome-with-extensions-disabled-turned-off)

Comment: @KalamalkaKid i tried first 4 answers and they don't work here. First one looks like something I need to do but maybe file structure changed after 10 years :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable chrome extensions (when Chrome is unresponsive)?](https://superuser.com/questions/163692/how-can-i-disable-chrome-extensions-when-chrome-is-unresponsive)

Comment: @Destroy666 no, starting with --incognito open in incognito mode but still use all cpu and is unresponsive.

Comment: Rename the extensions folder and replace it with an empty one. Should be `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions`, copy and paste it to Explorer location bar ([via](https://superuser.com/questions/1124944/disabling-an-extension-manually-in-chrome/1124952#1124952)). Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543896/where-does-chrome-store-extensions) SO question for the directory.